# Asp/Razor CreateUser method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Okay, here's the issue in general. I am using `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider` for log in and registration for my website. And I am using Razor syntax (.cshtml files) for my view pages. One of these pages is a "forgot password" page. In this page, I want to use some code that is only supported by`WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity`. I've added the necessary code to web.config and all that, so that's not my problem.

My problem is that now my Register code doesn't work. Specifically, the CreateUser method. What is happening is that, even though VisualStudio shows the CreateUser method as `MembershipProvider.CreateUser`, when the function is actually called (I've looked at the stack call, so I'm sure of this) is `WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUser`. This function is not supported by the system (according to the exception statement). Apparently, the CreateUser methods for both MembershipProvider and WebMatrix have the exact same signatures, so this appears to be the problem.

Here's the method code, for what it is worth, but, this code is created automatically, when I create the website in VisualStudio. And, by the way, I cannot change the parameters:
`_provider.CreateUser(userName, password, email, null, null, true, null, out status);`

So, what is the solution? I would like to be able to explicitly specify the method in the code. Something like: `_provider.MembershipProvider.CreateUser(userName, password, email, null, null, true, null, out status);` Alas, I am not allowed to do this. So, is there a way to specify which function to call? Or maybe some other solution?

Comment: Could you post your whole controller action where `CreateUser` is called?

Comment: The <Membership> section of your web.config file might be helpful too.

Comment: Mitchell says: I would be happy to post the code. However, all of the code involved is automatically generated when creating a ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application in Visual C#. The only web.config code I've added is:<add assembly="WebMatrix.WebData, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="WebMatrix.Data, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>  This code was added to <assemblies> I will add the code for the function, if there is a request, but the problem is not the code, per se, but how it is interpreted by the system

Comment: You're really not giving us much to help you with.  Sure, you may have narrowed down that this particular function call is the culprit, but without seeing how the code interacts with the rest of the application, and the configuration of the app, we may never figure it out.  Who knows?  Maybe you missed something in your configuration that someone else will see at a glance, or you're getting your `_provider` object incorrectly (I honestly have no idea what `_provider` is without seeing how you're getting that object)?  An extra set of eyes looking at the whole picture never hurt.

Comment: Its almost always better to *show* us what the problem is, than to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use

```
Membership.CreateUser()
```

or

```
Membership.Provider.CreateUser()
```

Without seeing more of your code, its difficult to help.

Comment: I've tried both of of these inserts into my code. The problem is this. Say I do the code Membership.CreateUser(), Then the VisualStudio Editor gives me the error message: System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider does contain a definition for 'Membership' {Same kind of error message for Membership.Provider.CreateUser()} The issue is that Visual Studio editor is already assuming the namespace MembershipProvider for the function. So, you can't "add" any namespaces--the function is already fully defined. But, at runtime, the call is to the WebMatrix type function.

Thanks, Mitchell

Answer (score 0):

Before you dig any further, you might want to check and see if the new **ASP.NET Universal Providers** by Microsoft work for you. They will most likely be the default providers for the next version of ASP.NET.

- [Introducing System.Web.Providers - ASP.NET Universal Providers for Session, Membership, Roles and User Profile on SQL Compact and SQL Azure - Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Universal Providers - 0.1 - NuGet gallery](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/System.Web.Providers)

In your case, the equivalent provider would be `System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider`